# Cannot run click function when jquery delay() is active

Tags: jquery

i create simple form using jquery(*ajax*) and when user submit form the success message will appear `slideDown()` and delay for 6 second after that will `slideUp()`  but when delay() is active i cannot close this box .

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    //ajax will submit form
    //$.ajax({
    //type: form34.attr("method"),
    //url: form34.attr("action"),
    //data: form34.serialize(),
    //success: function (data) {   ...
    //when success run this
    $(".message_div").addClass("message_success").slideDown().delay(6000).slideUp();
});

$(".close").click(function () {
    $(".message_div").slideUp();
});
```

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/YjxcT/3/)

Comment: I think this is not a good candidate for delay, you may use setTimeout instead

Comment: try to use stop() jquery method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this code works for me.

```
 $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".message_div").stop().slideUp();
 });
```

Comment: ur welcome :)
i can't provide a jsfiddle because, i can't see the `<img src="http://www.mybook.my/images/close.png" alt="" class="close">`. but i'm pretty sure of the stop() method to use. hehehe. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can stop all the currently-running animation using [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for that element

try this

```
 $(".close").click(function () {
   $(".message_div").stop(true,true).slideUp();
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/YjxcT/4/)